# Monte carlo server program

Tags: java

```
package montecarlo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author hafiz
 */
public class PICalcDistributedMaster {

ObjectOutputStream ostream;
ObjectInputStream istream;
Socket s;
String numThrows;

  public void go(){

          Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("Please enter number of throws: ");
          numThrows = input.next();
          int num = Integer.parseInt(numThrows);

          try{
               ServerSocket sock = new ServerSocket(100);
               s = new Socket("127.0.0.1",100);
               System.out.println("Waiting for connection");
               System.out.println("Connection received from " + s.getInetAddress());

               PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true);
               pw.println("Sending Number");
               pw.println(num);

               ostream = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
               ostream.flush();

               istream = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
               System.out.println("IO streams found");
               istream.read(); //reads the input stream

             }

          catch (IOException ie){
              ie.printStackTrace();
          }
   }

   public static void main(String [] args){
       PICalcDistributedMaster pim = new PICalcDistributedMaster();
       pim.go();

   }
```

}

i have adjusted the code to what you told me.I am still getting an error after running it more than once and i think it has to do with the garbage collector problem.My error is

```
java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:365)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:319)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:185)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:97)
    at montecarlo.PICalcDistributedMaster.go(PICalcDistributedMaster.java:31)
    at montecarlo.PICalcDistributedMaster.main(PICalcDistributedMaster.java:56)
```

I assume the problem is with the socket it is binding to.I have tried different kinds but i cant still proceed

Comment: If you want help you need to try to be a bit clearer on what your question is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to suggest programming in smaller chunks. You've got a *lot* of code here and I don't think most of it ever runs:

```
           ServerSocket sock = new ServerSocket(5000);
           s = new Socket("127.0.0.1",5000);
           s = sock.accept();
```

This code creates a server socket, binds it to a port.

Then you create a new socket `s` to connect to the server socket. (Which isn't yet listening.)

You *destroy* your new socket `s` with the `sock.accept()` result -- when you lose the last reference, the socket is free for garbage collection, and you only ever had one reference to it -- `s`.

The `sock.accept()` call probably ought to block until a new connection arrives. If it doesn't block, that means you triggered an exception even before all this code.

Incidentally, there's another instance of overwriting content nearly immediately after creating it:

```
          String message = "connection successful";
          message = (String) istream.readObject();
```

You'll *never* see `connection successful` from your program because you've overwritten the only reference you have to the string.

Probably the most egregious error in the entire program -- the one that is keeping you from making any real forward progress -- is that you throw away *all* the exception information:

```
 try{
       go(null);
    }
 catch(Exception e){
     System.err.print("Connection terminated");
  }
```

The `catch(Exception e) { /* print message */ }` means that you don't get *any* diagnostic information about what errors actually happened in your program. (Since you never use the parameter of `go()`, you should remove it completely and the needless `null` here, as well.)

One of these catch-all `catch` statements might be useful once you're confident that your product catches everything more specific, is nearly bullet-proof, and your customers demand an always-on reliable product. But it has no place in development -- you need to be alerted to faults in your programs with as much detail as possible so you can find and fix all your bugs.

Remove this. Get rid of your `process()` method completely -- it is only harmful.

Comment: i have adjusted the code.however the above problem is still what i am facing

Comment: This new code definitely looks _much_ better; good work. Your error message got cut off in your updated post, can you take a look at that? It could be that two quick calls to `bind()` isn't going to work unless you also set the [`SO_REUSEADDR` socket option](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setReuseAddress(boolean)). I think your `ostream` handling isn't quite right -- should it be wrapped around the `PrintWriter`? (I don't know Java streams as well as I could.)

Comment: somebody pls help.i have read most network programming books in java and i still cant get any headway.i know i have -4 votes on this question but i really need to submit it for an assg

Comment: After I removed the `package` line and used port `10000` rather than `100` (I'm on Linux, can't bind low ports), this program managed to connect to itself quickly twice in a row. Once it's connected, it doesn't do much, but the connections seem to be working just fine.